# Designing SQL database with two types of users

Tags: postgresql, database-design

So I'm trying to design a Postgresql database with two types of users.

Customers and Brands

A Customer cannot be a brand and a brand cannot be a customer.

Is this the right approach? I feel I may have some challenges when querying data.

[image]

Comment: There's nothing here to stop you adding data which makes a user be both a customer and a brand.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a good model or not depends mostly on how you use the tables:

- If you expect that many queries or foreign key constraints will refer to “brand and/or customer”, your proposed model may be the way to go.
- If the tables are mostly used separately, using only two tables might be better.

If your concern is mostly that the tables should share certain columns, you could also use PostgreSQL [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   username text NOT NULL,
   email text,
   password text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE brands (
   storename text NOT NULL,
   ...
) INHERITS (users);

CREATE TABLE customers (
   stripeuserid text NOT NULL,
   ...
) INHERITS (users);
```

Then `brands` and `customers` are separate tables, but they are guaranteed to have the same columns as `users` (and others in addition).

Then you can query `users` to see rows from both `customers` and `brands`, but you cannot use `users` as the destination of foreign keys to either `customers` or `brands`.

Comment: Where does person come from?

Also was wondering with my current setup, how would I setup a way that there is a main company admin account and that account can then create other accounts for their staff.

Comment: `s/person/users/`. Fixed. I don't understand the second part - that doesn't seem to be part of the data model, but of your program.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with foreign keys? or is inheritance a better way of doing it? It seems like in your example a user can be both a brand and a customer which isn't what I would like.

Also my second part is talking about is say a brand wants certain employees to have their own account (sorta like how you can have a main account, and then a developer account with specific permissions) how is the best way to set that up?

Comment: I think you misunderstood table inheritance, please read the documentation. It is just a way of sharing column definitions and an implicit `UNION`. `users` wouldn't contain any rows. Sure, you can use foreign keys; see the discussion in my answer.